# Optional parameters in Vanilla-JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parameters, default-parameters

I don't know how to make function arguments to be optional in a certain case.
The case is if I have at more than one argument and not the last one should be optional. I see the ejs templating engine solves this:

```js
ejs.renderFile(templatesPath, options, (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
         console.log(err);   
         error = err;
    } else {
         res.write(html);
         res.end();
    }
})
```

So if I don't pass the options parameter, the callback function will still be recognized as a callback function and not as the options object - and the role, assigned to it, remains to be callback function and not the role of the missed parameter - as it would normally.

So how can it be solved - in JavaScript - that I still define 2-3 or more arguments (in the function definition) but if I don't pass an optional one - which is not the last - that it doesn't change the passed parameters role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What matters is the order of the parameters. Therefore, you must repect it.

Just pass `undefined`, `null` or an empty object `{}` if the function does not support no value.

Below, `options` is declared but not valued (`undefined`). The order is respected, it will work.

You can keep this way: always declare variable to pass them to the function, and assign value to them only when you have it.

```
var options; 
ejs.renderFile(templatesPath, options, (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
         console.log(err);   
         error = err;
    } else {
         res.write(html);
         res.end();
    }
});
```